# utf-8 URLs in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, urldecode, angularjs-resource

My URL has some Arabic text in it. `$location.path()` displays the text correctly (decoded) but the browser URL is encoded and is not human readable.

How to make the browser URL display the correct Arabic text?

Comment: can you add some examples or screenshots of how your url and text looks ?

Comment: I want to display something like: /حب but I am getting /%D8%AD%D8%A8 in the browser